# Using setInterval to create a progress bar

Tags: javascript

I was hoping a kind soul might be able to assist.

I have a slideshow which auto-plays, my intention is to have the next button act as a visual aid, highlighting the when the next frame is coming in.
sync with the autoPlay interval.

Right now, the update func concludes too early, which is the best I have managed to do. Typically I have the clearInterval and setInterval conflicting creating shuddering animations.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    * { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    .carousel_wrapper {
      height: 50vh;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
    }
    .carousel_frame {
      width: 100%; height: 100%;
    }
    .carousel_controls {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    .prev, .next {
      height: 50px;
      width: 100px;
      background: aqua;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .next {
      background: linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, aqua);
    }
    .carousel_frame:nth-child(1) {
      background: red;
    }
    .carousel_frame:nth-child(2) {
      background: blue;
    }
    .carousel_frame:nth-child(3) {
      background: green;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      const homepage_carousel = new carousel();
    });
    function carousel() {
      const carousel = document.getElementsByClassName('.carousel_wrapper')[0];
      const frames   = [...document.getElementsByClassName('carousel_frame')];
      const prev_button = document.getElementsByClassName('prev')[0];
      const next_button = document.getElementsByClassName('next')[0];
      this.frameIndex = 1;

      prev_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.resetPlay();
        this.move(-1);
      })

      next_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.resetPlay();
        this.move(+1);
      })

      this.hideAll = () => {
        frames.forEach((f) => {
          f.style.display = 'none';
        });
      }

      this.show = () => {
        this.hideAll();
        frames[this.frameIndex - 1].style.display = 'block';
        this.update_bg();
      }

      this.move = (amount) => {
        this.frameIndex += amount;
        this.frameIndex = (this.frameIndex > frames.length ? 1 : (this.frameIndex < 1) ? frame.lengh : this.frameIndex);
        this.show();
      }

      this.update_bg = () => {
        let w = 1;
        let test = setInterval(adjust, 10);    
        function adjust() {
          if (w >= 100) {
            clearInterval(test);
            w = 0;
          } else {
            w++;
            next_button.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(to right, white ${w}%, aqua)`
          }
        }

        setInterval(adjust, 3000);  
      }
      
      this.autoPlay = () => {
        this.move(+1)
        this.update_bg();
      }

      this.resetPlay = () => {
        // clearInterval(timer);
        // timer = setInterval(this.autoPlay(), 4000);
      }

      this.show();

      const timer = setInterval(this.autoPlay, 3000);

    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='carousel_wrapper'>
    <div class='carousel_frame'>
      <span>Headline</span>
      <span>Description</span>
      <span>CTA</span>
    </div>
    <div class='carousel_frame'>
      <span>Headline</span>
      <span>Description</span>
      <span>CTA</span>
    </div>
    <div class='carousel_frame'>
      <span>Headline</span>
      <span>Description</span>
      <span>CTA</span>
    </div>
    <div class='carousel_controls'>
      <span class='prev'>Previous</span>
      <span class='next'>
        Next
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: change `setInterval(adjust, 10);` to `setInterval(adjust, 25);`, or rewrite to trigger next slide when animation finishes i.e one timer

Comment: @LawrenceCherone many thanks for your swift intervention - that worked immediately. I would not be called Dim, if it was not true. I typically see tutorials for setInterval using 1000's to denote milliseconds. What is 27 in your example?

Comment: np, its a fudged ms which *roughly* animates it to the end within 3 the seconds, is not an ideal solution. It would be better if you used [requestanimationframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) but would require abit of rewriting it and making it all based on one timer (3000 / 100) = 0 to 100 range when at 100 move to next slide, reset and repeat

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I will rewrite this to use request animation frame.